# When I use the "Boolean" modifier it doesn´t make new faces

Tags: modifiers, faces

I am new to Blender and I´ve decided to watch Blender Guru´s video on how to make an anvil. I´ve come to the second part where he uses a boolean modifier and
that´s where my problem appeared. When I use the boolean modifier to curve a cylinder shape into the anvil it also deletes the faces which in the video it does not. I think I followed every step so I can´t really tell where I´ve made the mistake but I can´t find a solution.

Here´s a link to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WxMwa0njGSM

And a screenshot:

[image: settings]

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a solution.. Instead of selecting BMesh I selected carve and as operation I chose union. Works fine.